# is it okay to allow password access to server?

Tags: ssh

I am getting ready to host my first webserver. I noticed that cloud providers allow access to your server either through a password or via ssh only. Do web administrators generally prefer the ssh only rout? Would this be significantly more secure?

I suppose I am a bit worried about ssh only because if I loose me keys then I can never access that server again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh login using keys is inherently more secure than using passwords, which are most often poorly chosen and can be brute forced if the server is configured insecurely.

Like passwords, keyfiles can be lost, but that shouldn't be a problem. Depending on the solution chosen, you can contact the hoster to reset the authentication mechanism for you, so you can login with a password. Or, if you chose a dedicated server, you can access it through its web control panel.

Comment: The idea that a host provider will reset the authentication mechanism is also scary to me. How easy would it be for someone to impersonate me and brake into my server this way?

Comment: That'd be very easy, and you'd most probably not realize it. Every managed product can somehow be accessed by the hosting provider, dedicated servers are a bit less exposed and colocated machines even less. But even the latter can be physically accessed by the personnel working in the datacenter...